A redirect to a tab or an empty state page with a link on it?
For a company web app that analyses specific data, the user first has to upload data to be able to use it.
The app has a tabbed structure:

'Overview'
multiple other analysis tabs
the last one is the 'files' tab

When users enters the app they land on the overview page, which has nothing in it, there is a link to the upload tab and a short description that they need to upload something.
I was wondering about your opinion to redirect users directly to the 'files' tab when the user enters for the first time and there is no data uploaded yet. So they will skip the 'overview' page. What do you think about this? It might be confusing because the user does not know about the tab structure yet and they land in the last item of the tab menu. Or is this good UX? After the upload they have to navigate back to the other tabs. Hope you can help me with this, Greetings!

Why not add the Upload functionality to the Overview page for the initial state of that page? If a file has been uploaded already then the overview shows the standard Overview details, but if there's no uploaded file then the user is prompted to upload. Or even add an interim step before getting to these tab pages where user has to upload a file to proceed. I assume none of the other tabs have functionality if no file has been uploaded, so there's no benefit to showing these tabs at this point anyway.

Thanks for your comment. The data can consist of multiple files and is not a fixed set. Files can be removed or added later. So there has to be a list of the files that are uploaded to be able to review them. You are correct that all the other tabs have no functionality until there is data uploaded. Do you suggest removing the other tabs until there is data and then add the tabs?

I recommend allowing users to input data immediately at the end of their onboarding process. Here's how the user journey would ideally flow:
Happy Flow:

User lands on the platform.
User completes the onboarding process.
User is directed to a screen where they can add data. (This is still onboarding)
After data entry, the user is taken to the dashboard.

Alternate Flow:

User lands on the platform.
User completes the onboarding process.
If the user chooses not to add data during the initial setup, We notify them that adding data is crucial for populating the dashboard. However, if they decide to skip this step, they can still add data later via the 'Add Files' tab.

This approach helps in building the user's understanding of how the platform functions as intended. (Mental Model)
Additionally, you can view the image from Hubspot below for a visual reference, or check the Hubspot user flow on Mobbin for further insight.
Hubspot on Mobbin

